# Preserve unicode whitespace characters during .NET XmlSerializer deserialize

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have a problem. I'm deserializing XML-document and performing a schema validation for it. This works fine but **if a field value contains a Unicode whitespace character (Tab/U+0009), it will be replaced with a space**.

I've narrowed this functionality down to schema validation. Without schema validation, the Unicode characters will be preserved. I believe the XmlReader performs normalization when performing the schema validation.

Here's the simplified code:

```cs
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    Schemas = ...,
    ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
    ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings
}
// ...
// doc is XDocument
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(doc.CreateReader(), settings)
{
    var deserializedObject = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

I found a suggestion to use XmlTextReader manually, but I can't set XmlReaderSettings for the reader that way. XmlTextReader would have a property **Normalize** that would (probably) fix my issue.

Another suggestion I found was to set XmlReader Normalization private property via reflection, but it seems that it has been removed in later versions as it seems it doesn't exist in .NET 6.

I can't edit the XML document or the schema file.

Any suggestions how to workaround this issue?

Comment: Try String Reader with your XDocument  : StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xdoc.ToString());  Then XmlReader.Create(sReader)

Comment: Creating the reader from StringReader doesn't work either.

Comment: Try adding to reader settings :  settings.IgnoreWhitespace = false;

Comment: Do you mean true? Anyway, IgnoreWhitespace doesn't work either.

Comment: I meant false so no whiespaces get changed.  It looks like validation is somehow changing the data.  How are you reading the xml into the reader?

Comment: I tried IgnoreWhitespace both ways, false is the default but neither one worked. Loading the XML is being done via the doc.CreateReader.

Comment: Just to be clear, the problem doesn't reproduce if you deserialize directly from `doc.CreateReader()`?  What if you deserialize from `XmlReader.Create(doc.CreateReader())` without the settings?

Comment: Also, how is the field whose tabs are getting replaced to spaces defined in the schema?  Is it `xs:string`, or something else?  According to https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch04_02.htm whitespace replacement should be done for every field except those of type `xs:string`.

Comment: the problem doesn't reproduce if I deserialize without the settings. Even just setting the ValidationType to None fixes the issue (but naturally removes the validation). I actually came up a stupid solution that maybe I just validate separately and then deserialize without validation. It's a bit ugly but should work around the issue.

Comment: Can you share a portion of the schema that reproduces the problem -- i.e. a [mcve]?  If the field has type `xs:string` then it looks to be a bug in Microsoft's validating reader, but if not it may be working as specified by the standard, and you will need a workaround.

Comment: It is actually xs:normalizedstring so I think it works as it should. I just needed a workaround that is working fine (so far).